# Apply rotation matrix determined by separate fixed point - python

Tags: python, pandas, rotation

I'm applying a rotation matrix to a group of points with the aim to align the points along the horizontal axis. Using below, the xy points I want to adjust are recorded in `x` and `y`.

I'm hoping to transform the points using the angle between `X_Ref` and `Y_Ref` and `X_Fixed` and `Y_Fixed`. I'm also hoping to transform the points so `X_Ref` and `Y_Ref` is at **0,0** once the rotation is completed.

The rotated points currently don't adjust for this. I'm not sure if I should account for the reference point prior to rotating or afterwards.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({  
    'Period' : ['1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2'],        
    'Label' : ['A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D'],                             
    'x' : [2.0,3.0,3.0,2.0,2.0,3.0,3.0,1.0],
    'y' : [2.0,3.0,-1.0,0.0,2.0,3.0,-1.0,1.0],     
    'X_Ref' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
    'Y_Ref' : [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],        
    'X_Fixed' : [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    'Y_Fixed' : [0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2],                
    })

np.random.seed(1)

xy = df[['x','y']].values
Ref = df[['X_Ref','Y_Ref']].values
Fix = df[['X_Fixed','Y_Fixed']].values

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plot_kws = {'alpha': 0.75,
        'edgecolor': 'white',
        'linewidths': 0.75}

ax.scatter(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], **plot_kws)
ax.scatter(Ref[:, 0], Ref[:, 1], marker = 'x')
ax.scatter(Fix[:, 0], Fix[:, 1], marker = '+')

pca = PCA(2)

# Fit the PCA object, but do not transform the data
pca.fit(xy)

# pca.components_ : array, shape (n_components, n_features)
# cos theta
ct = pca.components_[0, 0]
# sin theta
st = pca.components_[0, 1]

# One possible value of theta that lies in [0, pi]
t = np.arccos(ct)

# If t is in quadrant 1, rotate CLOCKwise by t
if ct > 0 and st > 0:
    t *= -1
# If t is in Q2, rotate COUNTERclockwise by the complement of theta
elif ct < 0 and st > 0:
    t = np.pi - t
# If t is in Q3, rotate CLOCKwise by the complement of theta
elif ct < 0 and st < 0:
    t = -(np.pi - t)
# If t is in Q4, rotate COUNTERclockwise by theta, i.e., do nothing
elif ct > 0 and st < 0:
    pass

# Manually build the ccw rotation matrix
rotmat = np.array([[np.cos(t), -np.sin(t)], 
                   [np.sin(t),  np.cos(t)]])

# Apply rotation to each row of 'm'. The output (m2)
# will be the rotated FIFA input coordinates.
m2 = (rotmat @ xy.T).T

# Center the rotated point cloud at (0, 0)
m2 -= m2.mean(axis=0)
```

Initial distribution period 1:

[image]

Intended distribution period 1:

[image]

Initial distribution period 2:

[image]

Intended distribution period 2:

[image]

Comment: Your initial distribution doesn't match the plot generated from your code. Why is that?

Comment: I don't understand the code snippet you've provided. Do you want to rotate so to align the horizontal axis with the line (X_Ref,Y_Ref, X_Fixed,Y_Fixed) OR with the first principal component? In the snippet you've provided they happen to be the same but that's not necessary the case. If the former is true why do you do a PCA?

Comment: I agree with @SvetlinMladenov. Also, what does the 'Direction' column signify here?

Comment: Apologies. I've amended the question. The rotation is fine per se but I'm hoping to rotate the points but insert the reference point at 0,0.

Comment: Your 'intended output' and 'after rotation' in the amended question now looks the same. If you just want to update the rotated plot shown in the solution with the reference point at (0,0) then you can add the following line while plotting: `ax.scatter(list(np.repeat(0, len(Ref))), list(np.repeat(0, len(Ref))) , **plot_kws)` . I will add this as an update to the answer. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Each scatter needs to be shifted left. This will only exacerbate with more points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for any PCA if I understood what you try to achieve. I'd use complex number and that seems more straightforward :

**EDIT**

*There was a small mistake in the order of steps for translation previously. This edit will correct it as well as use your new dataset including changing ref/fixed points at different periods.*

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({  
    'Period' : ['1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2'],        
    'Label' : ['A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D'],                             
    'x' : [2.0,3.0,3.0,2.0,2.0,3.0,3.0,1.0],
    'y' : [2.0,3.0,-1.0,0.0,2.0,3.0,-1.0,1.0],     
    'X_Ref' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
    'Y_Ref' : [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],        
    'X_Fixed' : [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    'Y_Fixed' : [0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2],                
    })
```

First, transform fixed/ref points to complex numbers :

```
for f in ['Ref', 'Fixed']:
    df[f] = df['X_'+f] + 1j*df['Y_'+f]
    df.drop(['X_'+f, 'Y_'+f], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Compute the rotation (note that it is the opposite angle of what you stated in your question to match your expected results) :

```
df['angle'] = - np.angle(df['Ref'] - df['Fixed'])
```

Compute the rotation for every point (ref/fixed included) :

```
df['rotated'] = (df['x'] + 1j*df["y"]) * np.exp(1j*df['angle'])
for f in ['Ref', 'Fixed']:
    df[f+'_Rotated'] = df[f] * np.exp(1j*df['angle'])
```

Center your dataset around the "ref" point :

```
df['translation'] = - df['Ref_Rotated']
df['NewPoint'] = df['rotated'] + df['translation']
for f in ['Ref', 'Fixed']:
    df[f+'_Transformed'] = df[f+'_Rotated'] + df['translation']
```

Revert to cartesian coordinates :

```
df['x2'] = np.real(df['NewPoint'])
df['y2'] = np.imag(df['NewPoint'])
for f in ['Ref', 'Fixed']:
    df['NewX_'+f] = np.real(df[f+'_Transformed'])
    df['NewY_'+f] = np.imag(df[f+'_Transformed'])
```

And then plot the output for any period you like :

```
output = df[['Period', 'Label', 'x2', 'y2', 'NewX_Ref', 'NewY_Ref', 'NewX_Fixed', 'NewY_Fixed']]
output.set_index('Period', inplace=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plot_kws = {'alpha': 0.75,
        'edgecolor': 'white',
        'linewidths': 0.75}

plt.xlim(-5,5)
plt.ylim(-5,5)


period = '1'

ax.scatter(output.loc[period, 'NewX_Ref'], output.loc[period, 'NewY_Ref'])
ax.scatter(output.loc[period, 'NewX_Fixed'], output.loc[period, 'NewY_Fixed'])
ax.scatter(output.loc[period, 'x2'], output.loc[period, 'y2'], **plot_kws, marker = '+')

plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.show()
```

Result for period 1 :
[image]

Result for period 2 :
[image]

Comment: thanks for this. It's really close. My reference and fixed points will change though. But could I just pass these for each unique period in time. I'm also hoping the `reference` will be centered at 0,0 after the points have been rotated.

Comment: Just edited the answer (correcting the small mistake you saw as well as tailoring it for multiple periods). Hope this answer your need.

Comment: Brilliant. This is great @tgrandje

Answer (score 2):

Your question in unclear, since the "intended rotation" mentioned in the question can be already achieved if you plot `m2` which has been already calculated:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(m2[:, 0], m2[:, 1], **plot_kws)
```

Output:

[image]

But you have also mentioned the following in the question:

> The rotation angle is determined by the angle between X_Ref,Y_Ref and X_Fixed,Y_Fixed.

This is a totally different scenario. You can calculate the angle between two points by calculating the `arctan` between them, without having to use PCA at all. This can be done using [numpy.arctan](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arctan.html) as follows:

`t = np.arctan((Y_Fixed - Y_Ref/ X_Fixed - X_Ref))`

Here (X_Fixed, Y_Fixed) and (X_Ref, Y_Ref) are being assumed as two points.

For each row in your dataframe, you can then calculate the `x` and `y` values after rotation with respect to the angle between (X_Fixed, Y_Fixed) and (X_Ref, Y_Ref) in that particular row. This can be done using the following code snippet;

```
def rotate_points(row):
    t = np.arctan((row['Y_Fixed'] - row['Y_Ref']/ row['X_Fixed'] - row['X_Ref']))
    rotmat = np.array([[np.cos(t), -np.sin(t)], 
                   [np.sin(t),  np.cos(t)]])
    xy = row[['x','y']].values
    rotated = rotmat @ xy
    return rotated

df['rotated_x'] = df.apply(lambda row: rotate_points(row)[0], axis = 1)
df['rotated_y'] = df.apply(lambda row: rotate_points(row)[1], axis = 1)
```

Your dataframe would now look like this with the two new columns added to the right:

```
+----+----------+---------+-----+-----+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|    |   Period | Label   |   x |   y |   X_Ref |   Y_Ref |   X_Fixed |   Y_Fixed | Direction   |   rotated_x |   rotated_y |
|----+----------+---------+-----+-----+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------|
|  0 |        1 | A       |  -1 |   1 |       1 |       3 |        -2 |         0 | Left        |   -1.34164  |    0.447214 |
|  1 |        1 | B       |   0 |   4 |       1 |       3 |        -2 |         0 | Left        |   -1.78885  |    3.57771  |
|  2 |        1 | C       |   2 |   2 |       1 |       3 |        -2 |         0 | Left        |    0.894427 |    2.68328  |
|  3 |        1 | D       |   2 |   3 |       1 |       3 |        -2 |         0 | Left        |    0.447214 |    3.57771  |
|  4 |        2 | E       |   2 |   4 |       1 |       3 |        -2 |         0 | Right       |    0        |    4.47214  |
|  5 |        2 | F       |   1 |   4 |       1 |       3 |        -2 |         0 | Right       |   -0.894427 |    4.02492  |
|  6 |        2 | G       |   3 |   5 |       1 |       3 |        -2 |         0 | Right       |    0.447214 |    5.81378  |
|  7 |        2 | H       |   0 |   2 |       1 |       3 |        -2 |         0 | Right       |   -0.894427 |    1.78885  |
+----+----------+---------+-----+-----+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Now you have your rotated `x` and `y` points as desired.

### UPDATE:

As per the amended question, you can add the reference point at (0,0) in your plot as follows:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(m2[:, 0], m2[:, 1], **plot_kws)
ax.scatter(list(np.repeat(0, len(Ref))), list(np.repeat(0, len(Ref))) , **plot_kws)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. It's a simplified version of what I've currently got. I'm just trying to _rotate_ the coordinates with the reference point at 0,0.